# JavaFX script not working after changing pages

Tags: java, javascript, webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

As noted above, once the user clicks on something that changes the page, the scripting using JavaFX no longer works.

hello.html

```
<div onclick="app.byeBye()">bye</div>
```

byebye.html

```
<div onclick="app.hello()">hello</div>
```

JavaApp.class

```
 public class JavaApp{

    public void hello(){
        //process some stuff here
        setURL("/hello.html");
    }

    public void byeBye(){
        //process some stuff here
        setURL("/byebye.html");
    }

    private void setURL(final String uriString){
       Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
                JSObject win = (JSObject) webViewPanel.getWebEngine().executeScript("window");
                win.setMember("app",  new JavaApp());
                webViewPanel.loadURL(Browser.class.getResource(uriString).toExternalForm());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What must I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Try to get the window object and set "app" after webview's engine loads the url successfully. Namely when the engine's state is State.SUCCEEDED. See WebEngine's javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Uluk Biy is correct (but I can not make a comment an answer). Be sure to thumb him up if this is helpful.

> Try to get the window object and set "app" after webview's engine loads the url successfully. Namely when the engine's state is State.SUCCEEDED. See WebEngine's javadoc.

The WebEngine API page is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html